# How to initialize arrays in ES6/ES2015?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to skip array initialization in ES6 ? I have to enumerate below R twice, first to initialize counters, then to do actual count of A elements. I would rather do one enumeration

```
var A = ['red',1,'blue','red',1];   // test data

    var R = []; //associative array keeping count of A values

    A.map((item)=> R[item]=0); //initialize R with A elements as R indexes
    A.map((item)=> R[item]++); //count repeated A elelemnts in R
```

Comment: You are using not only numbers as array indexes. Though it is possible in Javascript, it would be better to use an object for it: `var R = {}`. Arrays with string keys are very tricky, you can't use `.forEach` and other functions, they will skip your string keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to initialise, you could do something like this:

```
A.forEach((val) => {
  if (R[val]) {
    R[val] += 1
  } else {
    R[val] = 1
  } 
});
```

Comment: oh yeah, based on yours I was able to build my one liner: A.map((item)=> R[item]?R[item] += 1:R[item] = 1);

Comment: I think mine was more legible ;)

Comment: Also, if you're not using the return value, you should use forEach, rather than map, since map would theoretically waste resources tracking the return value of each iteration and generating an array of them.

Answer (score 3):

So many ways to approach this differently... Here's one:

```
R = A.reduce(function (R, item) {
    R[item] = (R[item] || 0) + 1;
    return R;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to skip array initialization in ES6 ?

No, there isn't. You always need to **declare and initialize a variable** in javascript. There are no differences between *es* and *esnext* ([outside from strict-mode you can skip the declaration, but isn't a good practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)).

I didn't understand what you're trying to do...
It seems that you are counting each instance of a given element in a collection.

If you want to do that, you should use **an associative array** instead of an **indexeed array**:

```js
var collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 'me', 'you', 'she', 'me', 'you', 1];
var count = {};

collection.forEach(item => (count[item] = 1 + (count[item] || 0)));
```

You should keep in mind that associative arrays are indexed by string, so, you cannot have 'complex types' in your collection (eg: arrays), even, I think, number are converted to string. **In ES6** you should use `Map` to work around this issue.